# Custom JavaScript Scrollbars (jScrollPane) with Transform Scale error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, jscrollpane

I was hoping someone would know a way (or a direction) to correct the lack of support that jScrollPane has for rendering while Scale Transformed.

For containers that are scaled with larger scaleFactors the scrollbar often gets stuck at the bottom. The scroll bar also tends to accelerate away from the mouse drag to suggest a miss calculation.

I have also tried this approach with the library "mCustomScrollbar" and had the same results. Could this be a jQuery issue. I understand that jQuery UI (dragging mostly) has issues with transform scaling too.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8u3g/3/

```
#scene-1 {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; /* Safari and Chrome */
    transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

<div id="scene-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
            <p>lorem ipsume</p><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('.inner').jScrollPane();
});
```

I think jScrollPane for some reason can't recalculate the inner height of the container after it has been scaled.

Any support would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem. The problem is that when applying the "Scale" function `$.width()` always returns the original value, but `$.position()` returns depending on the scale.

The problem itself, I decided to finish the plugin. Now he is able to determine the current 
"scale" and divide it all the values ​​obtained using `$.position()`. This solves the problem. Here's a link to the plugin bugfixed: [jquery.jscrollpane.js(fixed-by-@snake_345).zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0baous9fydfom5/jquery.jscrollpane.js%28fixed-by-@snake_345%29.zip).

For an element to which you apply the plugin do not forget to add position: relative.

Comment: Just tried the link to the patched version in the post above. It does not appear to work.